# Ошибки при обновлении git с версии 1.8 на версию 2.20 в Centos 7.6

Tags: linux, git, centos, centos7

CenOS 7.6. из yum установилась 1.8 версия. При попытке обновиться на 2.20 выдает ошибку.
Что пошло не так?

```
# ./configure
checking for library containing clock_gettime... none required
checking for CLOCK_MONOTONIC... yes
checking for setitimer... yes
checking for library containing setitimer... none required
checking for strcasestr... yes
checking for library containing strcasestr... none required
checking for memmem... yes
checking for library containing memmem... none required
checking for strlcpy... no
checking for uintmax_t... yes
checking for strtoumax... yes
checking for library containing strtoumax... none required
checking for setenv... yes
checking for library containing setenv... none required
checking for unsetenv... yes
checking for library containing unsetenv... none required
checking for mkdtemp... yes
checking for library containing mkdtemp... none required
checking for initgroups... yes
checking for library containing initgroups... none required
checking for getdelim... yes
checking for library containing getdelim... none required
checking for BSD sysctl... no
checking for POSIX Threads with ''... no
checking for POSIX Threads with '-mt'... no
checking for POSIX Threads with '-pthread'... yes
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating config.mak.autogen
config.status: executing config.mak.autogen commands
# cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)
#git --version
git version 1.8.3.1
# make
SUBDIR git-gui
MSGFMT po/pt_pt.msg make[1]: *** [po/pt_pt.msg] Error 127
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Ошибка при обновлении с 1.8 на 2.20.

Comment: По сообщению гуглятся подобные ошибки при переходе на git новее 2.0 в разных дистрибутивах. Проверьте из какого пакета у вас установлен msgfmt, и последней ли он версии.

Comment: А добавить репозиторий EPEL не судьба? Или там тоже старая версия?

Comment: не смотрел. на сайте git для redhat рекомендуется из rpm ставить.

Comment: EPEL— это репозиторий пакетов для RHEL & CentOS. https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL

Comment: OK, они почему-то не захотели обновлять Git там... Ну по крайней мере вы теперь в курсе про этот репозиторий.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помогло выполнить установить gettext-devel:

```
yum install gettext
yum install gettext-devel
yum install curl-devel
./configure
make
make install
#git --version
git version 2.20.1
```